# Parsing a pair of ints with boost spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I have the following code:

```
std::string test("1.1");
std::pair<int, int> d;

bool r = qi::phrase_parse(
        test.begin(),
        test.end(),
        qi::int_ >> '.' >> qi::int_,
        space,
        d
        );
```

So I'm trying to parse the string test and place the result in the std::pair d. However it is not working, I suspect it has to do with the [Compound Attribute Rules](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html).

Any hints to how to get this working?

The compiler error is the following:

> error: no matching function for call
>   to 'std::pair::pair(const
>   int&)'

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should work. What people forget very often is to add a

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
```

to their list of includes. This is necessary to make `std::pair` a full blown Fusion citizen.

Comment: Perfect that worked.. is it written somewhere in the documentation? I could not find it, but maybe I just overlooked it.

Comment: Same problem, luckily found the solution here :-)

Comment: This also solved my issue. Many thanks to poster.